# Issue Integrating Amazon Simple Email Services API in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, email

I want to use the "verifyEmailIdentity" action which is defined in Objective-C as part of the Amazon Simple Email Service API but I'm having trouble doing so in Swift. I want to call the action in Swift code and have the documentation of the action defined in a pod but I'm not really sure how to go about this.

Here is some sample code but my program doesn't recognize the return type.

```
func createRequest(verifyEmailIdentityRequest: SESVerifyEmailIdentityRequest) -> AmazonServiceRequest {
    var request: AmazonServiceRequest = SESRequest()
    request.setParameterValue("VerifyEmailIdentity", forKey: "Action")
    request.setParameterValue("2010-12-01", forKey: "Version")
    request.delegate = verifyEmailIdentityRequest.delegate
    request.credentials = verifyEmailIdentityRequest.credentials()
    request.endpoint = verifyEmailIdentityRequest.requestEndpoint()
    request.requestTag = verifyEmailIdentityRequest.requestTag()
    if verifyEmailIdentityRequest != nil {
        if verifyEmailIdentityRequest.emailAddress != nil {
            request.setParameterValue("\    (verifyEmailIdentityRequest.emailAddress)", forKey: "\("EmailAddress")")
        }
    }
    return request
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_VerifyEmailIdentity.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the following snippet:

```
func verifyEmailIdentity(verifyEmailIdentityRequest: AWSSESVerifyEmailIdentityRequest) {

    // You should ideally set your configuration in app delegate
    // Set the region and cognito pool id
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
        regionType: AWSRegionType.Unknown,
        identityPoolId: "YOUR_POOL_ID")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
        region: AWSRegionType.Unknown,
        credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    let ses = AWSSES.defaultSES()
    ses.verifyEmailIdentity(verifyEmailIdentityRequest).continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
        if let error = task.error {
            // handle error here
        } else if let result = task.result {
            // handle result here
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Rohan